# Using Word Built in styles with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write to a word document from Excel using VBA. However when i try to apply the style heading 1 to the text it has to be English version of Office. How can i refer to the built in styles of office?

This is what i got now:

```
wrdApp.Selection.Style = "Heading 1"
wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:= "Test heading"
```

I want something similar to this (to make it international), however this does not work:

```
wrdApp.Selection.Style = WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1
wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:= "Test heading"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea.  Try simply:

`wrdApp.Selection.Style = wdStyleHeading1`

or without the reference to Word/late binding, use constant value

`wrdApp.Selection.Style = -2`

A list of enumerations can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211923(v=office.11).aspx